# C++ Struct initialization ways

Tags: c++, struct

I am learing C++ while I see some codes the structs are initialized in diffent ways, 
For example

```
 typedef struct Node {
        Node *p; 
        Node *n; 
        int data; 
    }Node;
```

What is the difference between these two ways, or both are same,

```
Node* root = new Node();
```

vs

```
Node* root = new Node;
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: In C++, don't use `typedef` and skip the `Node` after the closing brace.

Comment: @FrankPuffer May I know the reason for the suggested syntax ..

Comment: You are using C syntax. In C++ a `struct` is the same as a `class` except that all elements are public by default. Therefore you should declare a `struct` in the same way as a `class`.

Comment: @VivekAnanthan: Why don't *you* explain why you chose this obscure, obfuscating syntax? In which C++ training did you learn that?

Comment: @KerrekSB I am surfing through net and learing .. I seems I m not going in a good way .. Can you please suggest some good materials

Comment: Have a look at the [recommended books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) maybe.

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no difference, whatsoever.

Furthermore, in modern C++ there's also a third option too, and this is now the preferred syntax:

```
Node* root = new Node{};
```

In this case, all three alternative syntaxes are valid. As you proceed and learn more C++, you will find out in which situations some of these alternatives syntaxes can and cannot be used.

Comment: There actually *is* a difference. As the duplicate states.

Comment: When I tried printing values it is initialized with different values .. May be I need to dig into it ..